# Jquery to load java script content into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
    $("#footad").html('myjshere');
}, 15500);
```

Where it says myjshere I want to load this content into the div:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      AdServer.placeAd({"sz":"728x90","pos":1});
    </script>
```

But when I try just having it where myjshere is, it throws out a syntax error?

Any help?

---

To clear up the confusion I was put the JavaScript where myjshere is I just used the word myjshere as a place holder to show you what I was doing. Sorry for the confusion. The issue is that when I put the javascript within the jQuery it does not work and returns an error: invalid syntax.

---

Comment: `The issue is that when I put the javascript within the jQuery it does not work and returns an error: invalid syntax.` Show us this code

Comment: var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
    $("#myjshere").html("<script type='text/javascript'>     AdServer.placeAd({'sz':'728x90','pos':1});</script>");
}, 15500);

Comment: If the function returns a HTML string then my first code snippet should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your script is doing is putting 'myjshere' into the element with id 'footad' .

Is that what you are trying to achieve?

If I understood right, what you want, then this is the code:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
    $("#myjshere").html("<script type='text/javascript'>     AdServer.placeAd({'sz':'728x90','pos':1});</script>");
}, 15500);
```

Else if you want to replace myshere

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
    $("#footad").replace("myjshere","<script type='text/javascript'>     AdServer.placeAd({'sz':'728x90','pos':1});</script>");
}, 15500);
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess I had forgot to escape a character.

Comment: In the end I switched to **Iframes** as this was being difficult... and I am lazy, but thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `AdServer.placeAd` is a third-party function you want to implement. Therefore it depends on what the output of this function is. If `Adserver.placeAd` returns a HTML string you could do the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
   $("#footad").html(AdServer.placeAd({"sz":"728x90","pos":1}));
}, 15500);
</script>
```

My guess is that this code is running `document.write()` inside the function seeing as its called `placeAd`. Therefore you could add the code into the part of the HTML document you want it to appear like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
setInterval(function()
{
   AdServer.placeAd({"sz":"728x90","pos":1});
}, 15500);
</script>
```

Comment: Please see edit, sorry if I confused you. It is returning a html string, but I am using this technique as part of an auto refresh system, so it would need to be done where the whole div is updated.

Answer (score 0):

i better dont aks why you want to do this....

```
$('#footad').html('<script type="text/javascript">
AdServer.placeAd({"sz":"728x90","pos":1});
</script>');
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want to see the js as plain text you can load it with:

```
var js = AdServer.placeAd({"sz":"728x90","pos":1});
$("footad").html(js);
```

but will the js function placeAd return html? if not you must give an target to the AdServe class. like Adserver.target("#footad");

if this all is not that what you need, you must give more informations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

     var myjshere = AdServer.placeAd({"sz":"728x90","pos":1});
     $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function()  {
             $("#footad").html(myjshere);
          }, 15500);
     });

</script>
```